# Load md file remotely using fetch api and parse it on client/browser

Tags: javascript, client, blob, markdown, fetch

I want to load an .md file using fetch API and I need to parse it using `marked`

I'm having trouble grabbing the file via fetch api, i'm getting nothing back with `response.blob()` and `response.arrayBuffer()`.

```
fetch('http://s3.amazon.com/some_bucket/some_file.md')
 .then(response => response.blob())
 .then(result => console.log(result));
```

I want to then take the result and pass it to a react component to render it.  I will be parsing it using marked (from npm).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're getting the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error response. That is, you're making a cross-domain request and thus violating the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Basically, you need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on your S3 Bucket. Exactly how to do it, you can [read here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html).

Also, just as a quick test, you can prefix the URL you're trying to fetch with `https://crossorigin.me/` like this:

```
fetch('https://crossorigin.me/http://s3.amazon.com/some_bucket/some_file.md')
 .then(response => response.blob())
 .then(result => console.log(result));
```

which should make the request succeed. This is just for testing, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm actually not getting that error, I'm able to download the file directly if i put the link in the browser.

Comment: Actually you were right, it was a cors error, thanks